# redirect stderr of my program to config.log

Tags: c, autoconf

I want my configure script to run a custom compiler. `autoconf` knows nothing about this language, so `AC_TRY_COMPILE` won't do.

If I simply run the compiler without using macros, its stderr is printed to terminal, however, I want to do the same redirections as for C compiler and be affected by `--quiet` flag.

Standard macros do something like:

```
$CC ... 2>conftest.err
cat conftest.err >&5
```

but it's not documented.

Comment: Try asking a question.

Comment: Try running the compiler with stderr dup'd to stdout, which is going to config.log.  (eg, 2>&1)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's the documented macro for `config.log` file descriptor: `AS_MESSAGE_LOG_FD`

https://www.gnu.org/software/autoconf/manual/autoconf-2.69/html_node/File-Descriptor-Macros.html#AS_MESSAGE_LOG_FD

usage example:

```
echo foobar >&AS_MESSAGE_LOG_FD
```